# A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

how to remove this type of warnings in wordpress blog in console debug page A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script wordpress

check attached image , how can i remove this warnings?

[image]

Comment: i am also facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

There is not so much detail but I am assuming that you are embedding Google Publisher tags script into your website.

You probably are using some old embed method for GPT which uses `document.write` as its basis and therefore causes this error.

What you need to do is to use newer embed method like asynchronous one.

Here you can find more information
https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1638622?hl=en&ref_topic=4389931